# insert data and return it as json

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have below code, which is inserting data into a mysql database. However when the data is added i want to return this row as json. Is it possible to get this from the current insert query or would i have to make a new select query and if yes, then how do i retrieve the added id from this insert query?

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO camps (title, body, longitude, latitude, image) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('ssdds', $title, $body, $longitude, $latitude, $link);
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

The inserted id is available from [`mysqli::$insert_id`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php). You either need to build the row manually from the insert data, or run a `select`:

```
$id = $db->insert_id;
$result = $db->query("select * from camps where id = $id");
$json = json_encode($result->fetch_assoc());
```

Comment: `$id` is guaranteed to be an integer, so it's fine